# How to get list of categories and Keyword as a single XML | TOM API | R5.3

Tags: tom

I am using TOM APIs and trying to save list of categories and keywords as a single list. I am using

```
 Publication pub = tdse.GetPublication(publicationUri);
            ListRowFilter rowFilter = tdse.CreateListRowFilter();
            rowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", ItemType.ItemTypeCategory | ItemType.ItemTypeKeyword);
            rowFilter.SetCondition("Recursive", true);

            catandkeyList.LoadXml(pub.GetListItems(ListColumnFilter.XMLListDefault, rowFilter));
            catandkeyList.Save(Server.MapPath("Keyworddetails.xml"));
```

But only list of categories are getting saved as a result. Can some one suggest if there is any other way to setCondition for Row filter for both Categories and keywords?

```
 rowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", ItemType.ItemTypeCategory | ItemType.ItemTypeKeyword);
```

I only have publication ID as input parameter.

Comment: You may have to get Categories and then Keywords. The R5.3 (TOM) documentation also explains `CreateListRowFilter()` is "for backward compatibility only. New code should use GetObject or GetNewObject instead." Would `GetListKeywords()` work for you?

Comment: I agree with Alvin and think you may have to first define and save the category and then add the keywords.

Comment: Thanks Alvin and Robert for your suggestion. I will try this.